# Should oil be changed every 3000, or 5000 miles?

Tags: oil

I've always heard that the oil in a car should be changed every 3000 miles, but I read the manufacturer's suggested maintenance guide, and it says to change it every 5000 miles. Which is correct, or is it something entirely different, and why?

Comment: What does the vehicle's manufacturer recommend? There is no one answer that applies across the board.

Comment: As the question says, the manufacturer's maintenance guide says 5000 miles.

Comment: Not a pro question. Please see [this](http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/3/making-a-site-for-professionals)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're looking to change oil at a set mileage interval you should use the maintenance interval set by the vehicle manufacturer. More frequent changes aren't necessary however you may wish to change oil more frequently based on driving conditions (lot's of stop & go, short drives.)